# How can I register another Firebase user while I stay signed in? After registering, it switches my account

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js

Below is the method I am using for my register button.

```js
async registerAdmin() {
  const email = this.email;
  const password = this.password;

  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), () => {});

  try {
    setPersistence(getAuth(), browserSessionPersistence);

    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), email, password);
    const user = userCredential.user;

    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
      fullname: this.nAdminFullName,
      email: user.email,
    });

    console.log(`Successfully registered new user: ${user.uid}`);

    this.snackbar = true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error registering new user: ${error}`);

    this.snackbar = true;
  } finally {
    unsubscribe();
    
    onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(`User is signed in: ${user.uid}`);
      } else {
        console.log('User is signed out');
      }
    });
  }

  this.RegisterDialog = false;
}
```

When I use the method above, it registers the user but it directly logs in and switches the account I'm currently in. How can I prevent this?

I've tried the code but it just registers then switches the current user or account. I need to just register a new account while I stay signed in from my firebase account. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth says "If the new account was created, the user is signed in automatically." For your purpose, you probably want to use the admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user